# module 'tensorflow.contrib.rnn' has no attribute 'BasicLSTMCell'

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

When I try to run

```
lstm_fw_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)
```

I get the error mentioned in the title.

Is this due to the tensorflow version? How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `rnn.BasicLSTMCell` with [`tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/rnn_cell/rnn_cells_for_use_with_tensorflow_s_core_rnn_methods#BasicLSTMCell). See more details [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6432).

Comment: Thank you. My problem has been solved, but a new problem has emerged: (
Statement: outputs = rnn.static_bidirectional_rnn (lstm_fw_cell, lstm_bw_cell, X),
Error: AttributeError:, module,'tensorflow.contrib.rnn', has, no, attribute,'static_bidirectional_rnn'

Comment: You're welcome :) This post may be relevant: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7569. If your original problem was solved, I would suggest to ask a new question on stack overflow with your new problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is due to conflicts between versions of Tensorflow. The `rnn` package interface is changing rapidly.

Check your version and the version of the API you are using.